# No permissions or objectgears record does not exist

Tags: objectgears

I create a record in Filesystem class in ObjectGears and display it in the list. However, when trying to display a record detail, the system tells me that I do not have access rights or the record does not exists. This looks like a bug to me.

Answer (score 0):

Check in the class detail whether Multiple columns are enabled and there is no Control column selected. If so, disable Multiple columns.